# Select between two maps based on values

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this dataset:

```
%{
  "away" => %{
    "id" => "575ec304-wlk3-239n-3032jdns3944",
    "points" => 115
  },
  "home" => %{
    "id" => "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
    "points" => 120
  }
}
```

I want to return the map with the most points so that I end up with this.

```
%{
  "home" => %{
    "id" => "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
    "points" => 120
  }
}
```

I was thinking the `enum.find` would work for this but I haven't had any luck. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [`Enum.max_by/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#max_by/4) for this because you don't need a specific property of the item you're searching for, but instead you want the item itself with the most points.

```
iex> data = %{
  "away" => %{
    "id" => "575ec304-wlk3-239n-3032jdns3944",
    "points" => 115
  },
  "home" => %{
    "id" => "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
    "points" => 120
  }
}
iex> Enum.max_by(data, fn {_, value} -> value["points"] end)
{"home", %{"id" => "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "points" => 120}}
```

Comment: You need `|> List.wrap() |> Map.new()` or like to get back to the map.

Answer (score 1):

While `Enum.max_by/4` might seem a perfect fit here, the most performant solution would be to use plain old good [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reduce/3) with guarded clauses.

```rb
input = %{ ... }

Enum.reduce(input, nil, fn 
  {_, %{"points" => pe}}, {_, %{"points" => pa}} = acc when pa > pe -> acc
  e, _ -> e
end)
#⇒ {"home", %{"id" => "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "points" => 120}}
```

To get back from tuple to map, one might wrap the result with [`List.wrap/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html?#wrap/1) and [`Map.new/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#new/1)

```rb
input
|> Enum.reduce(nil, fn 
  {_, %{"points" => pe}}, {_, %{"points" => pa}} = acc when pa > pe -> acc
  e, _ -> e
end)
|> List.wrap()
|> Map.new()
#⇒ %{"home" => %{"id" => "583ec7cd-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c", "points" => 120}}
```